# ObjectContext disposed when use Dispose in EF

Tags: sql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I use Entity Framework on my project and I decided to change standard way, which means use - 'using'.
I write my DB layer for communicate Database, but sometimes return this error, please help me to fix this problem:

> An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed
>   and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Here is my BaseController Code:

```
//For Data Accsess
        public CBEntities DB
        {
            get
            {
                return DataAccsesLayer.DbeEntities;
            }
        }

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (DataAccsesLayer.DbeEntities != null)
                {
                    DataAccsesLayer.DbeEntities.Dispose();
                    DataAccsesLayer.DbeEntities = null;
                }
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

Data project:

```
//this part of code is member of Data project which is Data Layer
     public static class DataAccsesLayer
        {
            private static CBEntities _context;

            public static CBEntities DbeEntities
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_context == null)
                    {
                        _context = new CBEntities();
                        return _context;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return _context;
                    }
                }
                set { _context = value; }
            }
        }
```